# How I can deploy a couchDb index for my Hyperledger Fabric chaincode?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I'm trying to deploy a chaincode with a couchdb index, but it's not working.
I use Hyperledger fabric version 2.0 alpha and my chaincode is in go.

This is my index

```
{"index":{"fields":["price"]},"ddoc":"indexPriceDoc", "name":"indexPrice","type":"json"}
```

This is the folder structure:
chaincode\META-INF\statedb\couchdb\indexes\indexPrice.json

This is the query in my chaincode

```golang
queryString := fmt.Sprintf("{\"selector\":{\"timeSlot\":\"%s\"},\"sort\":[{\"price\":\"asc\"}], \"use_index\":[ \"indexPriceDoc\",\"indexPrice\" ]}", subscribe.TimeSlot)

iterator, err := stub.GetQueryResult(queryString)
```

When execute the query in my log file I find this error:

```
2019-06-12 09:59:05.714 UTC [shim] handleGetQueryResult -> ERRO 005 [0f072238] Received ERROR
2019-06-12 09:59:05.714 UTC [offer] Error -> ERRO 006 Error querying offers:  GET_QUERY_RESULT failed: transaction ID: 0f072238990b15b22696060305140880c6694028c1fac300511090f433dc2583: error handling CouchDB request. Error:no_usable_index,  Status Code:400,  Reason:No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields.
```

What is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

shutdown the network and install and instantiate the chaincode with the indexes again.
I too faced the same issue when more than one index is set.

Comment: We can restart the couchdb container provided named volumes are defined for the same.

Comment: I think it could just be done by upgrading the chaincode. I have tried it and it works.